Redirecting API from Chrome to Localhost: Missing Headers (Auth token) in Request
I am currently working on a Chrome extension using declarativeNetRequest that will be used to redirect APIs. While the extension works perfectly for redirecting various APIs, I've encountered an issue with requests redirected to localhost—specifically, the headers are missing due to that my localhost app throwing an authentication error as the token is missing.
For example, I can redirect from POST https://example.com/100/task to POST http://localhost:3000/100/task.
Interestingly, I also use a paid extension called Requestly, which successfully redirects APIs to localhost with all headers intact. After initially using Requestly-specific API, I disabled it and tested my extension; it then passed the headers to localhost as well, and the extension worked as expected for that specific API only.
I suspect that Requestly alters some Chrome settings that enable this functionality, but I have been unable to pinpoint what exactly has changed.
If anyone has insights or suggestions on how to ensure headers are included in requests to localhost, I would greatly appreciate your help!
Thank you!
My Manifest.json file :
 "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "API Redirect",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "declarativeNetRequest",
    "declarativeNetRequestFeedback",
    "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "logo5.png",
    "48": "logo5.png",
    "128": "logo5.png"
  },
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://*/*" 
  ]
}

My code to set the new rule in chrome :
 // Create the new redirect rule
    const redirectRule = {
        id: ruleId,
        priority: ruleId,
        action: {
            type: "redirect",
            redirect: {
                regexSubstitution: toUrl
            }
        },
        condition: {
          
            regexFilter: fromUrl,
            requestMethods: [method.toLowerCase()], 
            resourceTypes: ["xmlhttprequest"]
        }
    };

    // Update the dynamic rules in your background script
    await chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
        addRules: [redirectRule], // Add the new rule
        removeRuleIds: [ruleId] // Remove old rules if any, using the ID
    }, () => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error("Error updating rules:", chrome.runtime.lastError);
            callback(false); 
        } else {
            console.log("Redirect rules updated successfully.");
            callback(true); 
        }
    });

